# Use of \c in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am editing someone else scripts and I see s/he has used this `\c` very often like

```
echo "bla bla \c"
```

which when used simply prints

```
bla bla \c
```

on the screen.

So, I was wondering why use it or may be I am missing something, because it is doing nothing at all ? I checked escape characters and I didn't find any such thing as well. Is there any special use of \c in shell scripts, mainly in bash and korn shells ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/echo-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The \c keeps the cursor on the same line after the end of the echo, but to enable it, you need the -e flag:

```
echo -e "bla bla \c"
```

Answer (score 11):

I think the attempt is to terminate echo without a new line.

If it does not work on your system, you can replace this way,

```
echo "test \c"; echo " same line"
```

can become,

```
echo -n "test"; echo " same line"
```

An easier change will be (as suggested by `Neil`, +1 there),

```
echo -e "test \c"; echo " same line"
```

Comment: Using printf is more portable than echo -n.

Comment: @William, I completely agree. But, when you are porting scripts, a short trick like the `-e` or `-n` works faster.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) states that:

> **\c** Suppress the < newline > that otherwise follows the final argument in the output. All characters following the '\c' in the
>   arguments shall be ignored.

Basically a POSIX XSI-conformant `echo` utility should exit when it finds a **\c**, as is apparent from the following commands:

```
echo -e "foo bar \c baz" "quux"
```

Answer (score 1):

No automatic line break, [apparently](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1eschars.htm#CShellUse):

> Use in UNIX Shells
>
> UNIX Korn shells use the \c escape character to signal continuation (no automatic line break):
>
> echo "Enter the path to the data file: \c"

Answer (score 1):

NAME
       echo - display a line of text

SYNOPSIS
       echo [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
       echo LONG-OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

```
   -n     do not output the trailing newline

   -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

   -E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)

   --help display this help and exit

   --version
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the behavior of 'echo' varies depending on the shell used.
With a simple Bourne shell, '\c' will be interpreted by default (so the cursor remains on the line).
With Bash, it is not interpreted by default (so the string '\c' is displayed), so you must add the '-e' option to enable it.