# genrule cmd causes "Missing Terminating '"' character when building Envoy w/ bazel

Tags: escaping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bazel, envoyproxy, building

I am trying to compile an open source project called Envoy using Bazel (located here: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy). I am getting this error message when trying to run the build script:

[image]

The genrule code causing this issue is located in the file source/common/version/BUILD and looks like this:

```
    genrule(
    name = "generate_version_number",
    srcs = ["//:VERSION"],
    outs = ["version_number.h"],
    cmd = """echo "#define BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER \\"$$(cat $<)\\"" >$@""",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)
```

The error "missing terminating '"' is coming from somewhere in that cmd argument to genrule, but I can't figure it out. I have tried moving the quotes around about 1,000 different ways and I continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have git configured to translate the `\n` line ending in `VERSION` to `\r\n`. `$()` command substitution strips the `\n` in the intended configuration, but with yours there is still a `\r` left over. You can check by looking at how many bytes the `VERSION` file has, it should be exactly the number of printable characters + 1 (11 right now for `1.21.0-dev`).

Try cloning the repository with git from WSL, which will default to `\r` line endings. I'm guessing you used a git client from outside WSL, which will default to `\r\n` Windows newlines.

Instead, you might have `core.eol` set to `crlf` instead of `native` in your WSL gitconfig. That seems kind of unusual, but if so just set it to `native` for either this repository or globally.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383411/415337 has more details about this behavior with command substitution if you're curious.

Comment: Interestingly, like you say, `VERSION` does have a newline at the end (`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/envoyproxy/envoy/main/VERSION | hexdump -C`), but that doesn't get rendered in the github UI: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/VERSION

Comment: Yes, most text files include a trailing newline. Most git-related tools (and some text editors) display a message when it's missing. I think github's UI uses a symbol to indicate a lack of trailing newline, but it's been a while since I saw one.

Comment: Right, I was expecting two lines, with the 2nd being empty

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is saying that there are two missing terminating quotes: on line 1, and on line 2. So the file probably looks like this:

```
#define BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER "1.20.0-dev
"
```

Edit: The file actually does have a newline at the end (github UI doesn't appear to render it for some reason...), so the below probably isn't what's going on.

---

The [`VERSION` file](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/3b27d1d34f282be8a35d23b0417d6c90a6804ce2/VERSION) doesn't appear to have a new line at the end, so what I guess is happening is that `echo` is adding a newline. Try changing `echo` to `echo -n`.

What's kind of strange though is that I can see the same behavior (echo printing a newline at the end) on the terminal in linux, but not within a bazel build:

```
$ echo -n 1.0.0 > version.txt

$ hexdump -C version.txt 
00000000  31 2e 30 2e 30                                    |1.0.0|
00000005

$ echo "$(cat version.txt)" > txt ; hexdump -C txt
00000000  31 2e 30 2e 30 0a                                 |1.0.0.|
00000006

$ echo -n "$(cat version.txt)" > txt ; hexdump -C txt
00000000  31 2e 30 2e 30                                    |1.0.0|
00000005

$ cat BUILD
genrule(
    name = "generate_version_number",
    srcs = ["version.txt"],
    outs = ["version_number.h"],
    cmd = """echo "#define BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER \\"$$(cat $<)\\"" >$@""",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

$ bazel build version_number.h
INFO: Analyzed target //:version_number.h (5 packages loaded, 9 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:version_number.h up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/version_number.h
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.236s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions

$ cat bazel-bin/version_number.h
#define BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER "1.0.0"
```

So not sure why offhand.

Comment: I tried with echo -n, still got the same result. I was reading that some shell versions of echo use '\c' to stop echo from adding a new line, but where in that string """echo "#define BUILD_VERSION_NUMBER \\"$$(cat $<)\\"" >$@""" would I put the \c?

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218863/use-of-c-in-shell-scripting

Comment: Also, pretty surprising that `echo -n` didn't change anything. What happens in WSL when you do "echo" and "echo -n" on the command line?